# Where is this Schoolgirl Plushie from?

Tags: merchandise

[image]

What is her name?  From Anime? Please tell me the answer Thank you

Comment: does she have any tags on her? if so do they have any brand name on them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure it's from My Teen Romantic Comedy Snafu, Yukinoshita Yukino Plush Doll

https://www.1999.co.jp/eng/10431204

The clothes pretty much the same with her school uniform. She looks like this
[image]