# Where is this Lion Plushie from?

Tags: merchandise, oreca-battle

[image]

What is his name?  From Anime? Please tell me the answer Thank you

Comment: again, as i said in my [other comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/50613/what-is-her-name-from-anime-please-tell-me-the-answer-thank-you/50614#comment65552_50613), does this have any tags on it? if so do they have any brand name on them?

Comment: Tag Don't tell any word on japanese name.

Comment: could you take a photo of it? especially if it has any logos or anything?

Comment: Logo 'Takara Tomy" Brand only  I have not seen any text in Japanese.

Comment: Takara Tomy is a huge Japanese toy manufacturer, but thanks to this info I was able to find the plushie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character is Varu from the [Oreca Battle](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=15913) series. (You can see him on the right side of the image found on the link above) It's based on the Japanese trading card game [Monster Retsuden Oreca Battle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Retsuden_Oreca_Battle)

Also found the exact same plushie [here](http://www.presentoy.com/oreca-battle-soft-toy-03-varu/).

Comment: Oh,I found that! Thank you so much for your helping